# Prevent replacing <input type="submit"> with <button>

Tags: theming

I am using Bootstrap 3 subtheme (7.x-3.1-beta2 ) on Drupal 7 for the administrative backend. It seems that the Bootstrap base theme replaces <input type="submit"> with a <button> element. That breaks the layout of the views backend.

I tried to change this by:

- copying button.func.php into the subtheme
- renaming the function according to the subtheme name
- modifying the output to return <input> instead of <button>

**Code in button.func.php**

```
<?php
function bootstrap_subtheme_adl_admin_button($variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $value = $element['#value'];
   if (!empty($element['#icon'])) {
     if ($element['#icon_position'] === 'before') {
       $value = $element['#icon'] . ' ' . $value;
     }
   elseif ($element['#icon_position'] === 'after') {
     $value .= ' ' . $element['#icon'];
    }
  }

return '<input' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>\n';
}
```

However, this does not have any visible effect. 
Any advise?

Comment: Did you clear cache?

Comment: @sam2de of course.

Comment: Is your function even called at all?

Comment: @Mołot maybe I am misunderstanding this, but the function is called by the base theme, I am just attempting to overwrite it in the sub theme. In fact, it works fine when I edit the function in the base theme.

Comment: Ok, but in the subtheme is it executed, but wrong results, or not called at all?

Comment: Not called at all. Actually I am trying to trace where it is even called in the base theme. @Mołot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading the question directly, you've copied `button.func.php` into your sub-theme, modified the code inside it, and then tried to see if your changes work?

If that's what you did, the problem is that *Drupal never sees the code*. Fortunately (if that is the problem) the solution is simple: copy the code from that file into your sub-theme's `template.php` file and make whatever changes are required. Be sure the function is correctly named (i.e. to override `theme_button`, you'd need `themename` + `button` = `themename_button()`). In your example above, your sub-theme would have to be named 'bootstrap_subtheme_adl_admin' in order for your function to be called even if the code is in the correct file.

---

Incidentally, the reason the `button.func.php` file works in the base Bootstrap theme appears to be [the theme's registry.inc file](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/bootstrap/tree/includes/registry.inc?id=7.x-3.1-beta2).

---

### Basic sub-theme how-to with Bootstrap

1. Download Bootstrap sub theme into `/sites/all/themes`; don't bother to enable the theme
2. Copy `bootstrap_subtheme` from the `/sites/all/themes/bootstrap/bootstrap_subtheme` to `/sites/all/themes/bootstrap_subtheme`
3. Move `/sites/all/themes/bootstrap_subtheme/bootstrap_subtheme.info.starterkit` to `/sites/all/themes/bootstrap_subtheme/bootstrap_subtheme.info`
4. Enable `bootstrap_subtheme`

### Overriding a theme function implemented by a parent theme

1. Set up parent and subtheme as described above
2. **Never edit the parent theme in any way**
3. Copy the theme function you want to modify from e.g. `/sites/all/themes/bootstrap/theme/system/button.func.php` into the file at `/sites/all/themes/bootstrap_subtheme/template.php`
4. **Change the name of the function** in `/sites/all/themes/bootstrap_subtheme/template.php` from `bootstrap_button` to `bootstrap_subtheme_button`

Comment: Thank you @bhotel for your answer and explanation. I thought so too, however, if I try to declare `function bootstrap_subtheme_adl_admin_button($variables) {}` in template.php I end up with a white screen of death. I am a bit confused. I really would like to do adjustments like those in the subtheme rather the base theme, but seem not to find out what the correct way of doing this is.

Comment: Well, the white screen of death means there's a PHP fatal error. Find out from the error log what that error is, and you'll likely have the solution to the problem. Also, please confirm: the machine name of your subtheme is `bootstrap_subtheme_adl_admin`?

Comment: oh well, the php error log shows that the issue is that `bootstrap_subtheme_adl_admin_button()` declared in template.php has been also declared in `button.func.php` in my subtheme (yes: `bootstrap_subtheme_adl_admin` is the machine name) - which, yes is correct: I declared the function there, but that didn't work. Now if this is cause of the error, doesn't this indicated that Drupal very well is aware of the code in `button.func.php` ?
Edit: If I remove the function from `button.func.php` in my sub-theme all is good again. Right. This still bugs me though.

Comment: That error **means the function has been defined with the same name in more than one place**. You've either a) renamed the function in the bootstrap parent theme so that it's the same as in your sub theme, or b) you have **not** renamed the function in your sub theme.

Comment: The issue was that the function was defined with the same name in `template.php` and `button.func.php` - both `bootstrap_subtheme_adl_admin_button`- in the sub-theme. Still haven't found a solution though. The function doesn't change the output when in `template.php` nor in `button.func.php`. The only way it seems to get the correct results is if I overwrite the function in the base theme. I can't wrap my head around it :/

Comment: You're doing something quite wrong then. I just tested my answer to this question with the latest Drupal 7 / Bootstrap versions. I'll add a short bit to the end of my answer explaining the steps.

Comment: You are correct @bhotel - did a clean installation and it works now. Sigh. No idea what went wrong. Thank you for your answer!